# Post a link to Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to post a link with Facebook PHP as in the example in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/. I've written this code:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/' . $idFacebook . '/feed', 'POST',
    array(
        'link' => $enlace,
        'message' => $mensaje,
        'name' => $nombreAplicacion,
        'caption' => 'Juega en ' . $nombreAplicacion,
        'description' => '...',
        'picture' => '...',
        'type' => 'link',
        'application' => array(
            'name' => $nombreAplicacion,
            'id' => AppInfo::appID() )
    ));
```

The problem is that the link which is posted is the link to my application insted of $mensaje. Is that a constraint or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$mensaje` when you `echo` it?

Comment: $mensaje is a plain text that the user writes and it is written completely in the facebook post.

Comment: I'm not interested in what it's *supposed* to be, I'm interested in its *actual value* when it gets sent to facebook.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, you helped me notice I did it wrong. The posted link was in fact correct. The problem was I didn't provide the correct $link